# Batch Script How to Set Variabes inside another variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i want to do something like this

1.bat

```
var1=The bot now At %PlaceName%
```

2.bat

```
SET PlaceName=Hotan
Echo %var1%
```

it should be like:

```
The bot now At Hotan
```

but it is shown like:

```
The bot now At %PlaceName%
```

Comment: I don't know enough about any of this to provide an adequate answer but this link may help you. http://cplusplus.bordoon.com/cmd_exe_variables.html

Comment: Have you tried the obvious `SET var1=The bot now at %PlaceName%` ?

Comment: yea i did.
SET var1=The bot now At %PlaceName%

Comment: i Wrote it wrong i mean SET Var1=The bot now at %PlaceName% @RyanBemrose

Comment: If you ran that `SET` line (and `PlaceName` was previously set), then Var1 has the text you want.  `echo %var1%` to see it.

Comment: Thank you @RyanBemrose i got it , i have a problem that the variables at a ini File but i will solve it thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "var1=The bot now At !PlaceName!"
call 2.bat
```

**2.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET PlaceName=Hotan
Echo %var1%
```

Another way:

**1.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "var1=The bot now At %%PlaceName%%"
call 2.bat
```

**2.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal

SET PlaceName=Hotan
call Echo %var1%
```

Comment: look at the next answer i explained everything