# Batch Script How to Set Variabes into another variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i asked a question but it was not fully Explained so that is my Question.

i got settings.ini inside it There is sections with variables

```
[HideAndSeekEvent]
EventRunning=[Hide And Seek Event] Has started at [ %placenameHS% ].
```

and got another batch file called ini.bat

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set file=%~1
set area=[%~2]
set key=%~3
set currarea=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("!file!") do (
    set ln=%%a
    if "x!ln:~0,1!"=="x[" (
        set currarea=!ln!
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("!ln!") do (
            set currkey=%%b
            set currval=%%c
            if "x!area!"=="x!currarea!" if "x!key!"=="x!currkey!" (
                echo !currval!
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

and another bat file called Getdata.bat to call variables from .ini file and for this section there is

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call ini.cmd settings.ini HideAndSeekEvent EventRunning') do (
    set EventRunningeHS=%%a
)
```

in my main .bat file iam calling the Getdata.bat file

in my main .bat i got some thing like this

```
SET placenameHS=Hotan
echo %EventRunningeHS%
```

it should show

```
[Hide And Seek Event] Has started at [ Hotan ].
```

But it show :

```
[Hide And Seek Event] Has started at [ %placenameHS% ].
```

[NOTICE] i do not SET The Place name i got it by SQLCMD Query

```
osql -S %Server% -U %SQLUser% -P %SQLPass% -d Dother_Events -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT Place_Name FROM _HideANDSeek_Map WHERE ID = %IDHS%" %osqluser% -b -w 9999 -h-1 -o .\Logs_in_use\HSLN7.txt
set /p HSLN7=<.\Logs_in_use\HSLN7.txt
```

Comment: `call echo %EventRunningeHS%` should expand inner `%placenameHS%`

Comment: @JosefZ: Yes, I already gave this solution in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958759/batch-script-how-to-set-variabes-inside-another-variable/36959503#36959503) to the other OP's question about the same topic...

Comment: @Aacini I foreboded that this kind of question must have an answer somewhere at SO. Too lazy to search :) However, I feel that the OP's question is well-elaborated and doesn't merit punishment by flagging as duplicate. Please give your answer...

Comment: @JosefZ: If you read the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958759/batch-script-how-to-set-variabes-inside-another-variable) you'll realize that the OP didn't posted any feedback to my answer. Instead, he posted a new question _as an answer_ with not a single explanation of why he did that, and after that he posted this new [duplicated] question! I don't know how to deal with users that post _"I explained everything"_ in a comment, but that explained nothing... **`:/`**

Comment: i just want to know what is the problem here ?!
If your answer in the other post help me then why i will add new Question ?!

Comment: and i posted a new question to explain my Full Question

Comment: In your other question I posted an answer. Did you tested it? It worked? If not, what was the problem? This is basic feedback that you should post if you would be interested in solve your problem, but you did _NOT_ posted a single detail about my answer! As @JosefZ's comment indicated, the solution to this question is _the same_ as my answer at the other question. Did you tested it? The problem here is that it seems that you are not really interested in a solution; otherwise you should posted any useful feedback to JosefZ's comment or to my answer by now (instead of post useless comments).

Comment: i tested it and i told you it dose not work for me i got the seem problem

Comment: and i just want to solve my problem and till now i got nothing because you are focus on the two posts i am new to use this site btw -_-

Comment: Please, _read_ your comments at the other question! You _never_ said something like "I tested this code, but not works"; you just posted an entirely different question with not a single explanation of why you did that! Sorry, but I am not a mind reader...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code and data you posted, and the proposed solution. These are the files I used in the test.

**settings.ini**:

```
[HideAndSeekEvent]
EventRunning=[Hide And Seek Event] Has started at [ %placenameHS% ].
```

**ini.cmd**:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set file=%~1
set area=[%~2]
set key=%~3
set currarea=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("!file!") do (
    set ln=%%a
    if "x!ln:~0,1!"=="x[" (
        set currarea=!ln!
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("!ln!") do (
            set currkey=%%b
            set currval=%%c
            if "x!area!"=="x!currarea!" if "x!key!"=="x!currkey!" (
                echo !currval!
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

**Getdata.bat**:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call ini.cmd settings.ini HideAndSeekEvent EventRunning') do (
    set EventRunningeHS=%%a
)
```

**main.bat**:

```
@echo off

call Getdata.bat

SET placenameHS=Hotan

echo Original output:
echo %EventRunningeHS%

echo Proposed solution:
call echo %EventRunningeHS%
```

This is the output when I run main.bat:

```
Original output:
[Hide And Seek Event] Has started at [ %placenameHS% ].
Proposed solution:
[Hide And Seek Event] Has started at [ Hotan ].
```